# How to make a ListBox Control Display Added Items Vertically instead of Horizontally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox, controls

My code adds an item to a ListBox:

```
Item anItem;

protected void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List theList = List.GetList();

    if (theList != null)
    {
        thelist.AddItem(anItem);
        Response.Redirect("anotherWebForm.aspx");
    }
 }
```

Now, my problem is that whenever I add more than one item to my listbox and display that listbox as follows:

```
 private void displayList()
 {
      string itemInfo = "";

      for (int x=0; x < anItem.TheList.Count; x++) // this line is working fine.
      {
          itemInfo = itemInfo + anItem.TheList[x].itemName + .... // this line is working fine.
      }

      lbList.Items.Add(itemInfo); //This line adds the next selected item right beside the previous item in a horizontal manner.  I want to display it in a vertical way.
  }
```

the `lbList.Items.Add(itemInfo);` adds the next item right beside the previous one and doesn't make a new line.  I want to make it display in a new line, not horizontal as follows in the output:

```
 Item listbox:
 - item1
 - item2 
 - item3
```

But what I'm getting is this instead:

```
 Item listbox:
 - item1- item2- item3
```

I tried putting `lbList.Item.Add(itemInfo)` inside the For Loop but all it does is produce the following:

```
  Item listbox:
  - item1
  - item1- item2
  - item1- item2- item3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
private void displayList()
{
  for (int x=0; x < anItem.TheList.Count; x++) 
  {
      
   string itemInfo = anItem.TheList[x].itemName 
   lbList.Items.Add(itemInfo); 
     
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Form_Load, just put below codes.   uxTablesListBox is list box name. But in bindingfunction, you need to bind datatable including "TableName" column.

In this way, your list box items will show vertically.

```
    uxTablesListBox.View = View.Details
    uxTablesListBox.GridLines = False
    uxTablesListBox.FullRowSelect = True
    uxTablesListBox.HideSelection = False
    uxTablesListBox.MultiSelect = False
    uxTablesListBox.Columns.Add("TableName", 259)
```